# rsync for backup but don't want to wipe ( not erase ) drive

Tags: backup, rsync

I am not sure how to even ask this question without explaining. Say I use rsync to backup drive-a to drive-b. Drive-a fails and all data is lost when the rsync went off it saw that drive-a had been erased so it erased drive-b.

I am trying to write an rsync script so this does not happen. this actually happened to someone I knew so it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario you described (failed source drive), rsync will **not** delete anything, because:

1. by default, *rsync does not delete anything* until you pass it the "--delete" option
2. even passing it the "--delete" option, *rsync will not remove a destination file if the source disk can not be accessed*. From the man page:

> If the sending side detects any I/O errors, then the deletion of any
>   files at the destination will be automatically disabled. This is to
>   prevent temporary filesystem failures (such as NFS errors) on the
>   sending side causing a massive deletion of files on the destination.
>   You can override this with the --ignore-errors option.

The only means to end up with a wiped target after source failure is to:

- mangle with advanced rsync options (see man page)
- have a source failure that present a seemly consistent, but empty, filesystem (which is a *very* rare possibility)

Anyway, I second the suggestion to use rsnapshot + hard links. I use this setup for backup purpose and it is very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this "someone you knew" *probably* ran this command with rsync:

```
sudo rsync -av --delete /src /target
```

Although, this is highly unlikely unless, maybe, he added the `--ignore-errors` option.

In any case, if you only consider **source drive** as possible failure you are missing the point of backup. Nowadays, the **cloud** is your friend.

To answer your question, the best possible solution you could use to avoid drive failure deletion on **target** with rsync would be to use `-b` with `--backup-dir=DIR` options for an incremental backup. Example:

```
sudo rsync -avb --delete --backup-dir=/backup/incremental /src /target
```

Above, original `/target` files, that are to be updated, are copied to `/backup/incremental` before the update process. Files deleted on `/src` that are now targeted for deletion on `/target` are simply re-named and placed in `/backup/incremental`.

Consider your first command with rsync to be a hard copy with `-n` = `--dry-run` option:

```
sudo rsync -avn /src /target
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you can set rsync up to not delete extraneous files. By default it doesn't. So if all the files are gone from drive-a, they should be fine.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5451/delete-extraneous-files-from-dest-dir-via-rsync

Comment: thank you for the quick response: So by default it will not wipe drive-b? So I wrote this a while ago and need to make sure it will not wipe the destination drive if drive-a has files removed:                                                   rsync -avXHh --inplace --numeric-ids --progress drive-a drive-b  . I am going to run some tests. I always thought the default was to remove files on B is the get removed on A?

Comment: no, by default, `rsync` will be more like a "copy" operation. However, sometimes you might want the `--delete` flag, because some files on A were deleted and you want them removed from B.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/). This uses rsync to create a backup based on hardlinks. On the server, multiple backups can be accessed without wasted space. So when your drive A is erased, only the newest backup will have the data "erased", but the old snapshots will still hold the data.

Another thing to do is using the options `--backup` and `--backup-dir` directly with `rsync`:

> -b, --backup
>
> With this option, preexisting destination files are renamed as each file is transferred or deleted. You can control where the backup file goes and what (if any) suffix gets appended using the --backup-dir and --suffix options.
>
> Note that if you don't specify --backup-dir, (1) the
>       --omit-dir-times option will be implied, and (2) if --delete is also in effect (without --delete-excluded), rsync will add a lqprotectrq filter-rule for the backup suffix to the end of all your existing excludes (e.g. -f "P *~"). This will prevent previously backed-up files from being deleted. Note that if you are supplying your own filter rules, you may need to manually insert your own exclude/protect rule somewhere higher up in the list so that it has a high enough priority to be effective (e.g., if your rules specify a trailing inclusion/exclusion of oq*cq, the auto-added rule would never be reached).
>
> --backup-dir=DIR
>
> In combination with the --backup option, this tells rsync to store all backups in the specified directory on the receiving side. This can be used for incremental backups. You can additionally specify a backup suffix using the --suffix option (otherwise the files backed up in the specified directory will keep their original filenames).